# In what Thread do XCUnitTestCases run?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I am testing a method, that uses a `Geocoder`. To make the test synchronous, I mocked the `Geocoder`, so that I can directly call the `completionHandler` inside my Unit-Test where needed.

This worked perfectly fine, until I introduced a code block in `Geocoder`'s `completionHandler` that runs on the main thread. (`DispatchQueue.main.async {}`).

I then noticed, that my Unit-Test does not pass anymore, as the assertions are called before the `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` block. I solved it by using expecations.

However, this made me wonder whether XCUnitTestCases run on a different thread than the main thread. I did not find anything in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

In Apple's documentation about testcases I found this and believe it to be an answer, however I can't be to sure. They write:

> Tests execute synchronously because each test is invoked independently one after another. But more and more code executes asynchronously. To handle testing components which call asynchronously executing methods and functions, XCTest has been enhanced in Xcode 6 to include the ability to **serialize asynchronous** execution in the test method, by waiting for the completion of an asynchronous callback or timeout.

So on the main-thread using callbacks (which are first class functions, making it possible?).

(source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html @ **Writing Tests of Asynchronous Operations**)